# How to get a double average in Collection of objects that have bytes using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an Employee Entity that has a Collection of Reviews, each Review has a byte grade.

Unnecessary details are omitted for brevity

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "employee",  cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Review> reviews;
}
@Entity
public class Review extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    private Byte grade;
}
```

How can I get an average grade for Employee using Stream?

Answer (score 1):

Average method exists in some special Stream classes, you have to cast to that classes first

```
OptionalDouble average = employee.getReviews().stream()
            .map(Review::getGrade)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .mapToInt(Byte::intValue)
            .average();
```

Don't forget to check null too.
I also recommend that you use Integer or int instead of Byte for convenience. It's not worthy to use Byte